# Does any timezone actually use the TimeZoneInfo IsFixedDateRule properly?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

My question is whether I need to ensure my code works with timezones that use the IsFixedDateRule property? It seems that none of the timezones that use this rule actually specify a transition date.

I'm writing some unit tests to exercise some utility functions that work with timezone information from the Microsoft TimeZoneInfo library.

According to their documentation on IsFixedDateRule at this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.transitiontime.isfixeddaterule(v=vs.110).aspx
if IsFixedDateRule is true then you get the date of the daylight savings transition from the TransitionTime property Day, Month and TimeOfDay.

However, I've enumerated the entire collection and can't find ANY timezones that use these properties. Although some timezones (e.g. Venezuala Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time) do have IsFixedDateRule=true, in all of these cases the transitionTimes are always 1st January at midnight.

Here's some sample code to demonstrate the issue. This test passes, but it shouldn't according to the above linked article.:

```
    [Test]
    public void TemporaryDSTMuckaroundTest()
    {
        var timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
        foreach (var timeZoneInfo in timeZones)
        {
            var f = timeZoneInfo.StandardName;
            foreach (var adjustmentRule in timeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules())
            {
                var a = adjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionStart.IsFixedDateRule;
                if (a)
                {
                    var start = adjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionStart;
                    var end = adjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionEnd;
                    Assert.IsTrue(start.Month == 1);
                    Assert.IsTrue(end.Month == 1);
                    Assert.IsTrue(start.Day == 1);
                    Assert.IsTrue(end.Day == 1);
                    Assert.IsTrue(start.TimeOfDay.Hour == 0);
                    Assert.IsTrue(end.TimeOfDay.Hour == 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are never going to find a lack of weirdness when you dig through DST rules, they are political decisions.  Cuba is special because they sometimes stay on DST time for an entire year.  Venezuela, the world's largest exporter of oil, is suffering from a severe energy crisis due to drought conditions.  Last move was changing their timezone offset by half an hour.  Probably best to interpret the results you got as "we gave up trying to keep track!" :)

Comment: One wonders why you need to test these bits?  Unless you are doing something extraordinary, the `TimeZoneInfo` API itself will handle all variations of adjustment rules it supports.  You rarely have to go down to this level.  If you are doing something more substantial, you might consider using [a better API](http://nodatime.org) instead.

Comment: Thanks Matt. there should be a Godwin's law equivalent of how many comments are posted on a date/time question before someone mentions Nodatime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual DST transitions are rarely at year boundaries.  You may see those in the data because Windows models changes on a yearly basis in the registry, and sometimes it is necessary to model one year differently than the next.

For example, consider a time zone with no DST, but going through a standard offset change in the middle of a year.  This may be modeled as a DST transition from year start to mid-year, or from mid-year to year-end - depending on whether the offset is increasing or decreasing.

As far as the `IsFixedDateRule` property goes, it directly maps to the `wYear` field of the `SYSTEMTIME` structure as used by the `DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` and `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` structures in the Win32 API, and in the underlying `REG_TZI_FORMAT` structure that matches the binary data in the Windows registry.  [The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724253.aspx) state:

> If the `wYear` member is not zero, the transition date is absolute; it will only occur one time. Otherwise, it is a relative date that occurs yearly.

So - the Windows API supports this, and therefore so does the `TimeZoneInfo` class.  Whether or not there are *actual* data populated in the current shipping versions of the Windows time zone data or not is insignificant.

Comment: You may also want to read: [Exploring Windows Time Zones with System.TimeZoneInfo](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/07/exploring-windows-time-zones-with-system-timezoneinfo-josh-free.aspx)

Comment: So is the timeZoneInfo class lying about the transition date then when it tells me that it is January 1? And where is the real date?

Comment: Not lying per se, because if you compare the prior year's base offset to the current one you'll see the difference.  So it is a transition in the rules.  It's just not necessarily the thing you are looking for - which appears to be the transitions in wall-time offsets (base + dst).  Honestly, if that's what you really need - NodaTime makes it *much* easier.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind the [DateStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.DateStart);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) and [DateEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.DateEnd);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) properties. The transition times are not *always* at 1. January. It depends also on the year. For example goverments can change dates of daylight savings. This is also the reason you can have more than one adjustment rule for one time zone: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework)

```
[Test]
    public void TemporaryDSTMuckaroundAdaptedTest()
    {
        var timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
        foreach (var timeZoneInfo in timeZones)
        {
            var name = timeZoneInfo.StandardName;
            foreach (var adjustmentRule in timeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules())
            {
                var startFixed = adjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionStart.IsFixedDateRule;
                if (startFixed)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                    Console.WriteLine(adjustmentRule.DateStart);
                    var start = adjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionStart;
                    Assert.IsTrue(start.Month == 1);
                    Assert.IsTrue(start.Day == 1);
                    Assert.IsTrue(start.TimeOfDay.Hour == 0);
                }

                var endFixed = adjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionEnd.IsFixedDateRule;
                if (!endFixed)
                    continue;

                Console.WriteLine(adjustmentRule.DateEnd);
                var end = adjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionEnd;
                Assert.IsTrue(end.Month == 1);
                Assert.IsTrue(end.Day == 1);
                Assert.IsTrue(end.TimeOfDay.Hour == 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know that transition times aren't always 1st January. In practice they should never be 1st January as it is a silly time of year to transition into or out of daylight savings. However it seems that every instance of a fixed date transition in the current library is dated January 1, which made me wonder whether it was actually obsolete code.